# ZFS write ordering issue after System Crash?

Tags: linux, multithreading, io, crash, zfs

I'm facing a write ordering issue with ZFS (version 0.7). Finding difficult to understand root cause since I'm new to ZFS internals. Any insight is highly appreciated.

**Problem:** The user application issues [pwrites](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pwrite) to certain zvol offsets. System crash occurs while application IO is ongoing. After system is back online, zvol data is inconsistent (not in order).

```
[Thread-#1] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1300000000, data=A00
[Thread-#1] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1342750000, data=(some random data)
[Thread-#1] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1342760000, data=(some random data)
[Thread-#1] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1342770000, data=(some random data)
[Thread-#1] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1342780000, data=(some random data)
[Thread-#1] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1300000000, data=B00
[Thread-#2] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1300000000, data=BA0
[Thread-#2] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1342fe0000, data=(some random data)
[Thread-#2] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1342ff0000, data=(some random data)
[Thread-#2] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1343000000, data=(some random data)
[Thread-#2] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1343010000, data=(some random data)
// After this point, all writes to offset other than 0x1300000000 do not persist
[Thread-#2] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1342bb0000, data=(some random data) 
[Thread-#2] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1300000000, data=BB0
[Thread-#3] Writes to ZVOL offset=0x1300000000, data=BBA
....more writes
```

Note that user application is multithreaded. All threads are writing to same zvol. Zvol is [opened](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) as block device using **O_DIRECT** which makes each write synchronous.

We see from above log, multiple threads write to offset `0x1300000000`. However for this offset each write is performed in **mutually exclusive** manner (both in-memory update and pwrite). I checked [`blktrace`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blktrace) for zvol and all offset to request queue are in correct order.

Consider below ZDB dump post system crash.

```
$ zdb -dddddd <zvol-path>

1300000000   L1  0:3140111000:8000 0:c0000:8000 20000L/8000P F=1002 B=357647/357647
1300000000    L0 0:314155a000:10000 10000L/10000P F=1 B=357647/357647
...
1342750000    L0 0:3141c0a000:10000 10000L/10000P F=1 B=357647/357647
1342760000    L0 0:3141c1a000:10000 10000L/10000P F=1 B=357647/357647
1342770000    L0 0:3141c2a000:10000 10000L/10000P F=1 B=357647/357647
1342780000    L0 0:3141c3a000:10000 10000L/10000P F=1 B=357647/357647
1342fe0000    L0 0:314248a000:10000 10000L/10000P F=1 B=357647/357647
1342ff0000    L0 0:314249a000:10000 10000L/10000P F=1 B=357647/357647
1343000000    L0 0:31424aa000:10000 10000L/10000P F=1 B=357647/357647
1343010000    L0 0:31424ba000:10000 10000L/10000P F=1 B=357647/357647
....
```

We see offset `0x1300000000` having **TXG 357647**. On reading offset `0x1300000000` we see the data as "BBA"! However, there are no writes to zvol after the point mentioned in log e.g. offset `0x1342bb0000` is completely missing.

It is possible that all writes after `0x1342bb0000` went into a later TXG and since system crashed the TXG was unable to sync. However this should also mean data at `0x1300000000` needs to be "BA0". How did a write done in future TXG landed up in prior one?

```
// Few details about system
$ cat /sys/block/zd0/queue/scheduler
none

$ uname -r
3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Crash is reproduced using `echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger` disabling filesystem sync.

Additional point - User application does not use fsync() calls. Used sparingly for performance reason.

Comment: From the very `open.2` man page you linked: "**O_DIRECT** Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this file. In general this will degrade performance, but it is useful in special situations, such as when applications do their own caching.  File I/O is done directly to/from user-space buffers. The O_DIRECT flag on its own makes an effort to transfer data synchronously, but does not give the guarantees of the O_SYNC flag that data and necessary metadata are transferred. To guarantee synchronous I/O, O_SYNC must be used in addition to O_DIRECT. See NOTES below for further discussion.

Comment: So "Zvol is opened as block device using O_DIRECT which makes each write synchronous." isn't quite true.  I suspect ZFS may still be caching your IO through the ARC. Do you see a difference in write ordering issues if you **severely** limit the size of the ARC and cause crashes?  If this is your only ZFS IO, if you see a performance degradation from limiting the size of the ARC when using `O_DIRECT`, that would be a pretty good sign that ZFS is ignoring `O_DIRECT`.

Comment: Yes I think you are correct @AndrewHenle. ARC is a cause of concern.
Although O_DIRECT is synchronous it does not have same effect as O_SYNC. O_DIRECT will only bypass linux cache and not ARC. ZFS will treat O_DIRECT writes  as async and not written to ZIL. Found a related article which covers sync/async explanation https://jrs-s.net/2019/05/02/zfs-sync-async-zil-slog/